# How to install custom plugin for Grafana running in Kubernetes cluster on Azure

Tags: azure, plugins, kubernetes, grafana

I have configured a Kubernetes cluster on Microsoft Azure and installed a Grafana helm chart on it.
In a directory on my local computer, I have a custom Grafana plugin that I developed in the past and I would like to install it in Grafana running on the Cloud.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/grafana#example-of-extravolumemounts

Answer (score 3):

You can use an initContainer like this:

```yaml
initContainers:
  - name: local-plugins-downloader
    image: busybox
    command:
      - /bin/sh
      - -c
      - |
        #!/bin/sh
        set -euo pipefail
        mkdir -p /var/lib/grafana/plugins
        cd /var/lib/grafana/plugins
        for url in http://192.168.95.169/grafana-piechart-panel.zip; do
          wget --no-check-certificate $url -O temp.zip
          unzip temp.zip
          rm temp.zip
        done
    volumeMounts:
      - name: storage
        mountPath: /var/lib/grafana
```

You need to have an emptyDir volume called **storage** in the pod, this is the default if you use the helm chart.
Then it needs to be mounted on the grafana's container. You also need to make sure that the grafana plugin directory is **/var/lib/grafana/plugins**